# how to recognize select2 dropdown and select2 multiselect seperatly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2, multi-select

i have two controls one `select2 dropdown` and another `jquery multi value select`

**select2 dropdown**

```
<select id="drp_me" class="select2-offscreen">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

**jquery multi value select**

```
<select id="mult_val" class="span6 select2">
  <option value="1">ONE</option>
  <option value="2">TWO</option>
  <option value="3">THREE</option>
</select>
```

but the problem is when i am passing these Ids to JS function and trying to display it's type both are showing the type as `select-one`

**JS**

```
$('#drp_me').select2();
$('#mult_val').multiSelect();
function displayType(id) // id = mult_val or drp_me
{
  var control=document.getElementById(id);
  console.log(control.type); // both controls showing as `select-one`
}
```

i am using jquery plugins for both controls `select2`  and  `multiSelect`. basically both are same select control (select). but physically they are different. `how i can differ these controls through code??`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding `multiple='multiple'` to `mult_val`? Because from your markup they are both single-select.

Comment: +1 [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/C5DK7/) shows type is recognised as `select-multiple` when adding `multiple` attribute.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl ok, then what will be the type for multi select?

Comment: @chriz as he told: `select-multiple`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<select multiple>`  for multiselect box:

```
<select multiple id="mult_val" class="span6 select2">
  <option value="1">ONE</option>
  <option value="2">TWO</option>
  <option value="3">THREE</option>
</select>
```

You can identify the control by its IDs using "#", so for select2 you can use $('#drp_me')...
and for multiselect you simply use its ID as above $('#mult_val')...